# Zend Form: Get array element in view script

Tags: arrays, forms, zend-framework, element

I want to display a title and a content field for each language. So, in the form, I have:

```
foreach ($languages as $language)
{
    // Add the title element
    $title = new Zend_Form_Element_Text($language);
    $title->setLabel($translate->_('News Title'))
          ->setBelongsTo('title');
    $this->addElement($title);

    // Add the content element
    $content = new Zend_Form_Element_Textarea($language);
    $content->setLabel($translate->_('News Content'))
            ->setBelongsTo('content');
    $this->addElement($content);
}
```

If I render the form in the usual way it works perfectly:

```
echo $this->form;
```

However, I want to render each field separately to include some HTML in the middle and other jQuery stuff. My problem is that I cannot manage to access those elements. I tried

```
foreach ($languages as $language)
{
    $this->form->getElement($language);
}
```

but it only renders 'content' element. Am I overriding 'title' element?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're overriding the Title element. The parameter you pass to `new Zend_Form_Element_Text($language);` (`$language` in your case) should be unique. Infact you can use it to identify and retrieve the element when you need.

To setup the param you can do something like this:

```
foreach ($languages as $language)
{
    // Add the title element
    $title = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('title-' . $language);

   ...
}
```

Comment: Then, where should the key (of the array) go?

Comment: Then, array keys are 'fieldname-'.$language which is not what I want. I'd like having language keys as array keys.